# How many dice sets is optimum for a four player group in Age of Rebellion?

Tags: star-wars-age-of-rebellion

How many dice sets would you consider optimum for a group of 4 people (including GM) who want as fast gameplay as possible without dropping more than 50 dollars?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, a group of FOUR.

Comment: Another option, which not everybody like: There are apps for that, not only the overpriced one by the publisher, but cheaper, less pretty ones as well. You need to trust your players, though. Plus side: They make the awkward math of this system easy.

Comment: One Option could be buying cheap clear dice and painting them yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My group, which is that size, finds that in most combats (when dice usage is most intensive) most players will be rolling three yellow dice most of time. (This is for a game that has only been running for half a dozen sessions so far).

You get two of those in a set, so to avoid people having to grab dice off each other mid-round, you should be looking at 1.5 sets per player.

Comment: The game is great...but the dice and books are almost too expensive (I know the market is limited,which makes sense).  My plan was to get two sets,and then the app...and later pick up more...

Comment: The app definitely helps, since you can add as many dice as you need for $5. But there's nothing like physically rolling dice.

Comment: True True, why I still by the real things

Answer (score 2):

Our group consists of GM + 4 players. We put our *Star Wars* dice in a pool, held by the GM. They sit in the middle of the table and whenever anyone (GM included) needs to roll, they pull from that pool. This keeps things moving along at a brisk pace. Although there are five dice sets in the pool, because of the group approach to dice it could easily be done with three.

Comment: Would not two dice sets work as well?

Comment: Probably. I was erring on the side of caution.